# Calculus II Contunuity

Tags: calculus

Which of the following functions is continuous at (0, 0)?

(i)$f(x, y)= \frac {(x^2y^4)} {(x^2 + 4y^4)}$ if  (x, y)  ≠  (0, 0)

0   if  (x, y)  =  (0, 0)

(ii) $ g(x, y)  = \frac {(xy^5)} {(x^6 + 4y^6) }$if  (x, y)  ≠  (0, 0)

0   if  (x, y)  =  (0, 0)

(iii)$  h(x, y)  = (\sqrt {\frac {(x^2 + y^2 + 4)− 2)}{(x^2 + y^2)}} $if  (x, y)  ≠  (0, 0)

1/4 if  (x, y)  =  (0, 0)

I have no idea about how to even approach this question. I checked the textbook but it was too abstract and there was no step by step example. I would appreciate if you can explain me how to solve this kind of questions.

Comment: Just find the limit at (0,0) if it exists. Hint:

Comment: Do I need to use the first equations or since in all of them x,y = 0,0 corresponds to a value, such as 0 or 1/4, I will say the limit exists?

Answer (score 0):

Just find the limit at (0,0) if it exists. Hint: approach (0,0) along a line,say $x=my^2$ in first case and change into one variable. So it becomes:$lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac {m^2y^4} {m^2+4}$. You can prove only non-existence this way. For existence you have to go by \epsilon-\delta or other 'abstract' proof:)

Comment: It limit is independent of m the limit may exist. If it depends on m you can straightaway say limit is non-existent